# Is it best to uninstall Java via Control panel or JavaRa software?

Tags: java

I see there is an update released for Java (oracle).

I have JavaRa software installed for removing old versions of Java. Should I remove the old one before I install the new one and which method of removal ? For example, should I only use JavaRa if Java wont uninstall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, uninstall the older version first. If you want, you can use something like CCleaner that will attempt to clean up any leftover files and/or registry entries.

Use the program's own normal uninstallation process as the first step. If you have any problems such as the newer version not getting installed and complaining about the older version still being present, use a 3<sup>rd</sup> party uninstaller or cleanup tool or even resort to manual uninstallation/cleanup as a last resort.